# React: 1. Radio button doesn't toggle/selected 2. State gets empty after filtering JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have two big problems in my code.

1. My radio button don't toggle/selected
   If I select one of the button it should be selected and you'll see the circle filled with color, but right now my button cannot be selected. I tried to set a state for that but it seems not working.
2. I'm trying to filter my json data by the value of radio button. When I first click on one of the radio button it works, but after that it won't work again. I'd like to know how I can fix this.

```
import fashion from '../data/fashion.json';

class App extends React.Component {

    state = { products: fashion }

    updateItem  = (filter) => {
        this.setState({ products: fashion})
        let filteredItem = this.state.products.slice();


        let products = filteredItem.filter(item => {
            if (item.category === filter || item.size === filter) {
                return true;
            }

        });
        this.setState({ products: products })
        console.log(products);

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="sidebar">
                    <SideBar 
                        onClick = {this.updateItem}
                        items = {this.state.products}
                    />

                </div>

                <main>
                    <Item 
                        items = {this.state.products}
                    />
                </main>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

```
class SideBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { checked: false }
    }

    getValue = (event) => {
        // console.log("Get value", event.target.value);

        // Trigers updateItem() on App Component
        this.props.onClick(event.target.value);
    }

    toggleChecked = () => {
        if(this.state.checked===false) {
            this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
            console.log("toggleChecked", this.state.checked);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <ul className="category_list">
                    <li>
                        <input 
                            type="radio"
                            value="shirt" 
                            checked={this.toggleChecked} 
                            onChange={(e) => this.getValue(e)}
                        />Shirts
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input 
                            type="radio"
                            value="jacket" 
                            checked={this.toggleChecked} 
                            onChange={(e) => this.getValue(e)}
                        />Jackets
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input 
                            type="radio"
                            value="skirt" 
                            checked={this.toggleChecked} 
                            onChange={(e) => this.getValue(e)}
                        />Skirts
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input 
                            type="radio"
                            value="pants" 
                            checked={this.toggleChecked} 
                            onChange={(e) => this.getValue(e)}
                        />Pants
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input 
                            type="radio"
                            value="S" 
                            checked={this.toggleChecked} 
                            onChange={(e) => this.getValue(e)}
                        />S
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input 
                            type="radio"
                            value="M" 
                            checked={this.toggleChecked} 
                            onChange={(e) => this.getValue(e)}
                        />M
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input 
                            type="radio"
                            value="L" 
                            checked={this.toggleChecked} 
                            onChange={(e) => this.getValue(e)}
                        />L
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }    
}
```

```
Item.js

const Item = (props) => {

    const renderedList = props.items.map((item) => {

    return (
        <li key={item.id}>
            <div className="image_container"><img src={item.image} alt={item.name} /></div>
            <p className="product_name">{item.name}</p>
            <p className="price">{item.price}</p>
            <p>Size: {item.size}</p>
            <p>Category: {item.category}</p>
        </li>
    )
    });

    return <ul className="products">{renderedList}</ul>
}
```

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Black Shirt",
        "price": "$4.99",
        "image": "201904041432_1.jpg",
        "size": "S",
        "category": "shirt"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Pink Medium Shirt",
        "price": "$6.99",
        "image": "201904041432_1.jpg",
        "size": "M",
        "category": "shirt"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Red Shirt",
        "price": "$3.49",
        "image": "201904190794_1.jpg",
        "size": "L",
        "category": "shirt"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Tight Skirt",
        "price": "$12.99",
        "image": "401902170012_1.jpg",
        "size": "S",
        "category": "skirt"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Short Skirt",
        "price": "$14.99",
        "image": "901904190003_1.jpg",
        "size": "M",
        "category": "skirt"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Winter Skirt",
        "price": "$10.99",
        "image": "401902170126_1.jpg",
        "size": "L",
        "category": "skirt"
    },   
    {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Black Jacket",
        "price": "$44.99",
        "image": "201902181237_1.jpg",
        "size": "S",
        "category": "jacket"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Denim Jacket",
        "price": "$56.99",
        "image": "042-901811090003_1.jpg",
        "size": "M",
        "category": "jacket"
    },     
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Rider's Jacket",
        "price": "$84.99",
        "image": "201902041846_1.jpg",
        "size": "L",
        "category": "jacket"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Blue Medium Shirt",
        "price": "$6.99",
        "image": "901904240035_1.jpg",
        "size": "M",
        "category": "pants"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The input `checked` prop doesn't take a function, it takes a boolean that indicates whether or not its checked.  Usually this will be a boolean from your state:

```
<input
   ...
   checked={this.state.checked}
/>
```

Note that since you have multiple radio buttons, having your state be a simple boolean isn't gonna be sufficient, since you need to know WHICH button is checked.  You can just set the `checked` state to be your input's `value` instead:

```
<input
   ...
   value="jacket"
   checked={this.state.checked === "jacket"}
/>
```

The function which sets your state should be apart of `onChange`, and should set the `checked` state to `e.target.value`:

```
    getValue = (event) => {
        this.props.onClick(event.target.value);
    }

    toggleChecked = (e) => {
        this.getValue(e);
        this.setState({ checked: e.target.value });
    }


<input
   ...
   value="jacket"
   checked={this.state.checked === "jacket"}
   onChange={(e) => this.toggleChecked(e)}
/>
```

You might want to adjust this based on your desired behaviour, but this should be a good starting point.  For example, if you wanted to allow multiple boxes to be checked, `checked` would probably be an array of booleans or an object map of booleans.

2. There's a few problems with your `updateItem` function:

   - Usually, if you're calling `setState` twice in one function, you're doing something wrong.  `setState` is asynchronous, so you can't really guarantee a particular behaviour when you're calling them in sequence.
   - For the same reasons as the first point, you can't do these things in sequence and guarantee anything useful:

```
this.setState({{ someState: someValue }})

// this.state.someState won't be equal to someValue for this statement, unless you're super lucky.
this.functionThatUses(this.state.someState);
```

I'd change the first few lines of your function to something like this:

```
updateItem  = (filter) => {
    //this.setState({ products: fashion})
    //let filteredItem = this.state.products.slice();
    let filteredItem = fashion.slice();

    let products = filteredItem.filter(item => {
        if (item.category === filter || item.size === filter) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    this.setState({ products: products })
}
```

... and see where that gets you.  Basically, don't use component state as a temporary variable/workspace - it's not intended/able to be used that way.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. It worked like a miracle! May I ask a couple of questions? Is it okay to setState by writing like this.setState({ products: products }) ? Am I overwriting the initial state or is it safe? And if I merge getValue and toggleChecked will there be any difference? Should I separate them or not necessarily? Thank you!

Comment: @kayak No problem.  For (1): you're safe that way.  `setState` does a shallow merge of the current state and the object you give it, so only the `products` property will be overwritten.  For (2), no difference if you merge the two functions.  I just left them apart so that my edits were easier to follow :)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much for your help! :D